# Next.js route API requests to root

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have this API handler

`pages/api/[slug]/[uid].ts`

I want to rewrite the requests to the root of my app, to: http://localhost:3000/[slug]/[uid]

What I need to do on `next.config` to achieve this?

Comment: How does your `next.config` look now ?

Comment: Its empty /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution is

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:slug/:uid',
        destination: '/api/:slug/:uid',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```